# Application is pushed from background on intent android

Tags: android

In our application,during server hit say logout there is a server hit and the user is navigated to Login screen .
If in the process of server hit the user clicks on device home and pushes the application to background,after server hi success even if the user is on device home, the user is force pushed to Login.

The same scenario happens while navigating to any activity after success of server response.

As for me i would like to navigate the user to other screen even if he is in background,bu still make the application be in the background until the user clicks and opens it from recent apps.

Please let me know your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and if you are looking for the same,

```
public boolean isForeground(String myPackage) {
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager
                    .getRunningTasks(1);

            ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(myPackage))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

The above method can be used to check if the user is still in your app. If it returns false, it means your app is either minimised or closed.

And it needs this permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

So if the app is minimised and opened again from recent apps, onResume() of your activity is called and you can do your stuff there.